# How to get the position() and level() in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following [html fragment](http://xpather.com/cGp6T2WW) for testing. To select all `<a>` text I can do:

```
descendant::div[attribute::id="nav_tutorials"]/descendant::a/text()
```

And to select all `a` nodes I can do:

```
descendant::div[attribute::id="nav_tutorials"]/descendant::a/node()
```

And to get all the `a` links I can do:

```
descendant::div[attribute::id="nav_tutorials"]/descendant::a/attribute::href
```

However, how would I retrieve the position of each element? That is, the index position within the parent, so (since it does 1-indexing) for the `<a>`:

```
<div class='w3-col l3 m6'>
  <h3>HTML and CSS</h3>
  1 -- <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/html/default.asp'>Learn HTML</a>
  2 -- <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/css/default.asp'>Learn CSS</a>
  3 -- <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/bootstrap/bootstrap_ver.asp'>Learn Bootstrap</a>
```

And finally, how can I get the 'level' of the item from the root node (if that's possible to retrieve, for example):

```
L1 (root, since xml uses 1-indexing)
<div id='nav_tutorials' class='w3-bar-block w3-card-2' style="display:none;">
    L2
    <span onclick='w3_close_nav("tutorials")'>times</span>
    <div class='w3-row-padding' style="padding:24px 48px">
        L3
        <div class='w3-col l3 m6'>
            L4
            <h3>HTML and CSS</h3>
            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/html/default.asp'>Learn HTML</a>
            <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button" href='/css/default.asp'>Learn CSS</a>
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtain element ***position*** by counting preceding sibling elements:

```
count(//a[.="Learn Bootstrap"]/preceding-sibling::*)+1
```

(Use `a` rather than `*` if only interested in position among `a` elements.)

Obtain element ***level*** by counting ancestor elements:

```
count(//a[.="Learn Bootstrap"]/ancestor::*)+1
```

Comment: cool, that's a neat approach! Though it wouldn't ignore the other elements when doing preceding siblings though, right? For example: http://xpather.com/sgpaYLE7. Oh, I see -- you mention use `a` rather than `*` (but at the end though).